# Handlebars - How to access template data in "each" scope?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, each

I use pre-compiled Handlebars templates.
I have the following code:

```
<div id="{{ns}}paymentMethodsTabs">
    {{#each paymentMethods}}
        <button id="{{ns}}{{paymentCardCode}}">{{paymentCardCode}}</button>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

In the first `div`, the `ns` template data is available and set.
But inside the `each paymentMethods` scope, I can't access it, I tried

```
<button id="{{../ns}}{{paymentCardCode}}">{{paymentCardCode}}</button>
```

But it doesn't work either. (the template returns `null` instead of the HTML code in that case, I guess that's because it can't find the reference somehow, but I don't get any error message and it's really hard to debug, any advice on this? *It happens when I run `Handlebars.templates[path](data)`*)

How can I run a `each` loop and provide the template data?

Here are the data I provide to the template:

```
{
  "ns": 'main-layout-default-',
  "paymentMethods": [{
    "paymentCardCode": "CB",
    "contractId": "1234"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Can you show exactly the data object that you pass. (Not necessarily values, but just the structure).

Comment: @PiotrJakubowski Done! Not much actually.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the ns thing from template? Shouldn't you call `Handlebars.templates[path](data)` instead of `Handlebars.templates(path, data)`?

Comment: Does `Handlebars.template**s**` exist in the API?

Comment: @code-jaff I don't think so, but my templates are pre-compiled and stored into `Handlebars.templates` as JS functions, I don't use `Handlebars.template` actually.

Comment: @PiotrJakubowski Yes indeed! It's what I do `Handlebars.templates[path](data)`, I miswrited it here actually, I'll change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mismatch of the library. My code was generated by the handlebars 3.0 version but I used the runtime 2.0 and that's why it failed.

So the solution is indeed the following:

```
<div id="{{ns}}paymentMethodsTabs">
    {{#each paymentMethods}}
        <button id="{{../ns}}{{paymentCardCode}}">{{paymentCardCode}}</button>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Thanks to @kpdecker who helped me out. https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1011#issuecomment-96694058

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here,

```
{
  "ns": 'main-layout-default-', // <= missing comma
  "paymentMethods": [{
    "paymentCardCode": "CB",
    "contractId": "1234"
  }]
}
```

Comment: No, this is *again* a mistake (because data are added dynamically, I didn't copy/paste the JSON but I wrote it and forgot that comma...) Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0):

The "ns" is outside of the "paymentMethods". It cannot go out of it's scope.

```
{
  "ns": 'main-layout-default-', 
  "paymentMethods": [{
  "paymentCardCode": "CB",
  "contractId": "1234"
 }]
```

}

Try

```
{  
  "paymentMethods": [{
  "ns": 'main-layout-default-', 
  "paymentCardCode": "CB",
 "contractId": "1234"
 }]
}
```

or else if the "ns" value is same for all the generated data, then try

```
<button id="main-layout-default-{{paymentCardCode}}">{{paymentCardCode}}</button>
```

Comment: The `ns` value is the same for all of them indeed, it's a namespace to apply to all elements. It must be dynamic, I cannot write it in hard.